# Other functions on eigenvalues besides trace and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

Given a linear transformation $\mathscr{A}: V \to V$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with the underlying field being $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $\mathscr{A}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n}$. We can define $\operatorname{tr}(\mathscr{A}) = \sum_{i} \lambda_{i}$, and $\det(\mathscr{A}) = \prod_{i}\lambda_{i}$. These are two commonly studied functions, and one can ask many interesting questions about them (which goes beyond linear algebra for instance [in convex analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147329/set-of-positive-definite-matrices-with-determinant-1-forms-a-convex-set)).

> However, it seems odd to me that I've never heard people using other different functions on eigenvalues. In particular we can define $\operatorname{oper_{1}}(\mathscr{A}) = \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\lambda_{i}\lambda_{j}$, or similarly $\operatorname{oper_{2}}(\mathscr{A}) = \sum_{1\leq i,j,k\leq n}\lambda_{i}\lambda_{j}\lambda_{k}$, etc. In this case we do not have $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n}$ ordered, but if we do. Say in decreasing order, we can define something like $\operatorname{oper} (\mathscr{A}) = f(\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n})$, where $f$ is some continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$($\mathbb{C}^{n}$) to $\mathbb{R}$($\mathbb{C}$).

**So are there any results on such functions. If no, why not?** Even beyond linear algebra, it might be useful in analysis.

Comment: Read about symmetric functions and the elementary symmetric functions.

Comment: Look at the traces of tensorial, symmetric, and exterior powers of $\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: Largest and smallest magnitude eigenvalues (and, if real, maximum and minimum eigenvalues) are sometimes of interest.

Answer (score 3):

The sums $c_k(\mathscr{A}) = \sum_{|I| = k} \prod_{i \in I} \lambda_i$ are related to the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial; specifically
$$
\det(xI - \mathscr{A}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (x-\lambda_i) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}  c_k(\mathscr{A}) \,  (-1)^{k} x^k.
$$

In general, a function $f \colon \mathbb{K}^n \to \mathbb{K} $ of the eigenvalues must be symmetric in order to be well-defined. Assuming that $f$ is a polynomial, one may use the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials to write $f = g(c_0, \ldots, c_n)$, where $g \in \mathbb{K}[X_0, \ldots, X_n]$.

For more general $f$ admitting a power series representation in multiple variables, one may apply the theorem to each homogeneous part.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to mention that people in geometric partial differential equations care about these objects. The key phrase here is [$k$-Hessian equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_equation). These are equations of the form: $$ S_k[u]=f $$ where $$S_k[u] = \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_k}\lambda_{i_1}\dots\lambda_{i_k} $$ and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix of a function $u$, that is, $S_k[u]$ is the $k$-th order symmetric polynomial of the eigenvalues of $D^2u$. If you're interested in this, there’s some motivation in the introduction of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04969).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a large number of functions are defined on the eigenvalues of matrices. An entire book by Nicholas Higham is devoted to the subject. My use of the subject has been on developing concentration bounds on matrices, see section 5.4 of the book located here [https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html). In particular Definition 5.4.2.